# NULLPointerException while using KNIME

Tags: text-processing, knime

I am trying to perform some simple text analysis using KNIME. My process begins by using a normal 'XLS reader' or a 'text reader', followed by 'row filter' which executes fine. This step is followed by 'Strings to document' to convert every string into a document. Following this step, no steps execute. I have tried using 'POS Tagger', 'BoW Creator', 'Row Filter', 'Number Filter' etc, but each one of these gives me a `'NULLPointerException'`. Why is this the case? 
My input document is a text file with about 300,000 rows coming from the database. I have checked that none of the rows in the file is NULL. 
How can I get rid of this error? 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of KNIME, text processing do you use? Have you changed the settings in File|Preferences|KNIME|Text Processing|Storage? Could you provide more details about the exceptions? (File|Preferences|KNIME|KNIME GUI|Console View Log Level might help to easier find the stacktrace.)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug and will be fixed asap. As a workaround you need to set the file store chunk size to a number greater than the number of documents you are processing. Say you are processing 200.000 documents set the File store chunk size to 210.000 or so. You can do this in the Textprocessing preferences: File->Preferences->KNIME->Textprocessing->Storage->File store chunk size

See also:
http://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-textprocessing/bow-error-when-processing-large-data

Comment: I tried this workaround but I still end up with the same error.

Comment: The bug will be fixed in version 2.10.1.